# Powershell Where-Object returning null

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to Powershell and I cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong with the Where-Object.

The following script executes perfectly fine (URL removed):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url [SomeURL] -UseWebLogin

Get-PnPListItem -List "workproretentiontest" |  Select-Object @{label="Filename"; expression={$_.FieldValues.FileRef}}, {$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef}
```

Showing these results:

[Powershell results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ674.png)

I need to filter for individual results here but I cannot figure it out (and many hours have been lost!)

I feel like i've tried every combination possible of the following but can't figure out why it wont work

```
| Where-Object {$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -eq "201700007"}
```

What does work is this when I ask for nulls ( as in every record is returned when executing the following) which means the $_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef is always returning null?? But I cant work out why

```
| Where-Object {$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -eq $null}
```

Any help or guidance would be massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The why you wrote this, there will be literally a property called `'$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef'` on the object, so you would have to reference it as such:

```
| Where-Object {$_.'$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef' -eq "201700007"}
```

But it would be better style, got give it a proper name in the first place, just as you did with `"Filename"`:

```
Select-Object @{label="Filename"; expression={$_.FieldValues.FileRef}},
  @{label="Date"; expression={$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef}} |
  Where-Object Date -gt "201700007"
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could just reference the label set to the field, thank you so much for your help and feedback.

Comment: @BenWood What `Select-Object` does, it always creates creates new objects, with the property names you specify.